# Convert decimal to thousands separator for specific cases in a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to convert decimal points in columns of a vast data.frame into thousands separators.

For example, I need to convert data similar to:

[image]

On data similar to:

[image]

I didn't find similar questions on the platform. I appreciate any help.

Here's the data in the example:

```
structure(list(x1 = c(2.678, 135.613, 6.082, 30.221, 85.809, 
160.804, 173.38, 3.323, 0, 597.91), x2 = c("16.282", "2.636.486", 
"95.2", "514.364", "2.226.858", "4.283.662", "1.565.147", "375.16", 
"4", "11.713.163")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Why is the fourth row in the x2 column 514.364 in your desired output?

Comment: Thanks for the note @benson23, I made the adjustment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use `ifelse()` to identify rows with more than 1 dots `.`, then remove the first `.` of these rows and multiply by 1000. If it contains only one `.`, just multiply the number by 1000.

```
library(string)
library(tidyverse)

# there would be warning message if you include the as.numeric() in the ifelse(), 
# therefore I separated it in two operations
df %>% mutate(across(everything(),
                     ~ ifelse(str_count(.x, "\\.") > 1, 
                              sub("\\.", "", .x), 
                              .x)),
              across(everything(), 
                     ~ as.numeric(.x) * 1000))

      x1       x2
1    2678    16282
2  135613  2636486
3    6082    95200
4   30221   514364
5   85809  2226858
6  160804  4283662
7  173380  1565147
8    3323   375160
9       0     4000
10 597910 11713163
```

One of the downside of this approach is that if it contains more than two dots, it probably won't work.

**UPDATE: I have borrowed idea from @Dion Groothof to improve this code, now it should work regardless of the number of dots**

```
library(string)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.numeric(gsub("\\.", "", .x))),
              across(everything(), ~ ifelse(.x < 100, .x * 1000, .x)))

      x1       x2
1    2678    16282
2  135613  2636486
3    6082    95200
4   30221   514364
5   85809  2226858
6  160804  4283662
7  173380  1565147
8    3323   375160
9       0     4000
10 597910 11713163
```

Answer (score 3):

Using **base R**, this will work too.

```
out <- data.frame(apply(df, 2, function(x) {
  x <- as.numeric(gsub('\\.', '', x))
  ifelse(x < 100, x * 1000, ifelse(x < 1000, x * 100, x))
}))
```

**Output**

```
> out
       x1       x2
1    2678    16282
2  135613  2636486
3    6082    95200
4   30221   514364
5   85809  2226858
6  160804  4283662
7  173380  1565147
8    3323    37516
9       0     4000
10 597910 11713163
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, which works for an arbitrary number of `.`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  imap_dfc(~ str_split_fixed(.x, "\\.(?=\\d+$)", 2) %>% as.data.frame %>% 
     set_names(str_c(.y, 1:2, sep = "_"))) %>% 
  map2_dfc(1:4, ~ if (.y %% 2 == 0) {str_pad(.x, width = 3, side = "right", 
     pad = "0")} else .x) %>% 
  unite(x1, c(x1_1,x1_2), sep = "") %>% unite(x2, c(x2_1,x2_2), sep = "") %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_remove_all(.x, "\\.") %>% as.numeric))

#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>        x1       x2
#>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1   2678    16282
#>  2 135613  2636486
#>  3   6082    95200
#>  4  30221   514364
#>  5  85809  2226858
#>  6 160804  4283662
#>  7 173380  1565147
#>  8   3323   375160
#>  9      0     4000
#> 10 597910 11713163
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Paul Smith, however I believe it didn't work well for rounded values. For example, the value 4 remained. The value 95.2 did not change to 95200 as desired.

Comment: @VeltonSousa: you are right! I am going to fix that immediately.

Comment: In which way is this more efficient than benson's or my approach?

Comment: Well, @DionGroothof, your approach does not work if there is more than two `.`, while mine works even in such cases.

Comment: @PaulSmith The number `1.111.713.163` will correctly be converted to `1111713163`, so what's the flaw then?

Comment: Yours, @DionGroothof, works for the number you say, but not benson's.

Comment: Moreover, @DionGroothof, your solution does not work if the number is `95.21`. The result of your code is `9521`, when the correct value should be `95210`!

Comment: @PaulSmith This seems to occupy you quite extensively, haha! But you're right. Both our approaches will fail if, for instance, the first number of `x2` would be `"16.2822"` instead of `"16.282"`, but I guess this is outside the scope of what the OP was hoping to achieve...

Comment: I do not think it is outside the scope of what the OP was hoping to achieve, @DionGroothof, as one of his numbers is `375.16` (only two digits after the `.`). Moreover, he said he had lots and lots of numbers! Anyway, you could try to fix your solution.

Comment: @PaulSmith I will try to wrap my head around it and come with a solution shortly, but due to lack of time (facing a paper's deadline) I unfortunately have to postpone this for now.

Comment: That is alright, @DionGroothof! I am myself familiar with paper deadlines pressure. And please be aware that it is very frequent to have here many alternative solutions for the same question, many times provided by the very same respondent to the same question. In my case, since I am trying to deepen my skills in `tidyverse`, I always try to find a solution with `tidyverse`, despite whether it is more or less efficient than the other possible approaches.

Comment: I can relate to that, @PaulSmith, as I have the same with `base` R solutions.